# MongoDB generates same ObjectId with new ObjectId in pipeline's $project stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pipeline, aggregation, projection

As last stage of my pipeline, I have a `$project` like this :

```
{
  ...
  anId : new ObjectId()
}
```

But mongo is generating the same Id for each document. I want it to generate a new different Id for each projected document. How to do so within the pipeline?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to generate new id for each document, because it runs a single transaction. you have to loop the result in your client side language and generate the object id.

Comment: If `anId` only needs to be a unique ID, I recommend using a type different than `ObjectId`, perhaps a UUIDv4.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, but I'm running mongo 4.2 without $function support. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it with the help of `$function` aggregation:

```
{
  anId: {
    $function: {
      body: function() {
        return new ObjectId();
      },
      args: [],
      lang: 'js'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: not working :( it returns nothing

Comment: it retruns the object for me on mongodbCompass, try to change retrun new ObjectId() to return new ObjectId().valueOf();

Comment: Creating a new ObjectId is a client-side oriented thing.   Although there does not seem to be specific guidance against it, there is something about generating the ID server-side that is unsettling.  Again, it is *not* the DB engine that generates an ObjectId for `_id` if unset -- it is rather the client-side driver that detects absence of field `_id` upon insert and creates it on the fly.